# Error when using MongoStore with Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express, session-store

I'm trying to store the sessions of my Express app in a MongoStore but I get an error at the connection. The error is a huge Object/JSON that I couldn't make sense of, so I tried every alternatives I found online but no luck so far...

Here is the app configuration:

```js
var express = require('express'),
    MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express),
    passport = require('passport');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.compress());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000);
    app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/img/favicon.ico'));
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
    app.use(express.session({
            secret: 'secret',
            store: new MongoStore({
                    db: dbOptions.db,
                    host: dbOptions.host,
                    port: dbOptions.port,
                    username: dbOptions.username,
                    password: dbOptions.password
            },
            function(err){
                    console.log(err || 'connect-mongodb setup ok');
            })
    }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(app.router);
});

app.configure('development', function(){
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});
```

And this is the error that is being logged in the console:

```
{ db:
   { domain: null,
     _events: {},
     _maxListeners: 10,
     databaseName: 'dbname',
     serverConfig:
      { domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _callBackStore: [Object],
        _commandsStore: [Object],
        auth: [Object],
        _dbStore: [Object],
        host: 'ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com',
        port: 27017,
        options: [Object],
        internalMaster: true,
        connected: true,
        poolSize: 5,
        disableDriverBSONSizeCheck: false,
        _used: true,
        replicasetInstance: null,
        emitOpen: false,
        ssl: false,
        sslValidate: false,
        sslCA: null,
        sslCert: undefined,
        sslKey: undefined,
        sslPass: undefined,
        serverCapabilities: [Object],
        name: 'ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017',
        _readPreference: null,
        socketOptions: [Object],
        logger: [Object],
        eventHandlers: [Object],
        _serverState: 'connected',
        _state: [Object],
        recordQueryStats: false,
        socketTimeoutMS: [Getter/Setter],
        db: [Circular],
        dbInstances: [Object],
        connectionPool: [Object],
        isMasterDoc: [Object] },
     options: { w: 1 },
     _applicationClosed: false,
     slaveOk: false,
     bufferMaxEntries: -1,
     native_parser: undefined,
     bsonLib:
      { Code: [Function: Code],
        Symbol: [Function: Symbol],
        BSON: [Object],
        DBRef: [Function: DBRef],
        Binary: [Object],
        ObjectID: [Object],
        Long: [Object],
        Timestamp: [Object],
        Double: [Function: Double],
        MinKey: [Function: MinKey],
        MaxKey: [Function: MaxKey],
        promoteLongs: true },
     bson: { promoteLongs: true },
     bson_deserializer:
      { Code: [Function: Code],
        Symbol: [Function: Symbol],
        BSON: [Object],
        DBRef: [Function: DBRef],
        Binary: [Object],
        ObjectID: [Object],
        Long: [Object],
        Timestamp: [Object],
        Double: [Function: Double],
        MinKey: [Function: MinKey],
        MaxKey: [Function: MaxKey],
        promoteLongs: true },
     bson_serializer:
      { Code: [Function: Code],
        Symbol: [Function: Symbol],
        BSON: [Object],
        DBRef: [Function: DBRef],
        Binary: [Object],
        ObjectID: [Object],
        Long: [Object],
        Timestamp: [Object],
        Double: [Function: Double],
        MinKey: [Function: MinKey],
        MaxKey: [Function: MaxKey],
        promoteLongs: true },
     _state: 'connected',
     pkFactory:
      { [Function: ObjectID]
        index: 16051204,
        createPk: [Function: createPk],
        createFromTime: [Function: createFromTime],
        createFromHexString: [Function: createFromHexString] },
     forceServerObjectId: false,
     safe: false,
     notReplied: {},
     isInitializing: true,
     openCalled: true,
     commands: [],
     logger: { error: [Function], log: [Function], debug: [Function] },
     tag: 1387402758191,
     eventHandlers:
      { error: [],
        parseError: [],
        poolReady: [],
        message: [],
        close: [] },
     serializeFunctions: false,
     raw: false,
     recordQueryStats: false,
     retryMiliSeconds: 1000,
     numberOfRetries: 60,
     readPreference: undefined },
  collectionName: 'sessions',
  internalHint: null,
  opts: {},
  slaveOk: false,
  serializeFunctions: false,
  raw: false,
  readPreference: 'primary',
  pkFactory:
   { [Function: ObjectID]
     index: 16051204,
     createPk: [Function: createPk],
     createFromTime: [Function: createFromTime],
     createFromHexString: [Function: createFromHexString] },
  serverCapabilities: undefined }
```

It's pretty obscure so I have no idea in which direction I should search.

**EDIT 1:**

Ok thanks that makes more sense now but the thing is I tried to log an error because the sessions aren't stored in MongoDB and I don't understand why. I added a try catch block around the setup of the MongoStore to see if an error was triggered and there is none so I have no clue why it's not working...

This is how passportjs store and retrieve sessions:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(_id, done) {
    var userProvider = new UserProvider();
    userProvider.findUser({ _id: _id }, function (err, users) {
            if(users.length > 0) { done(null, users[0]); }
            else { done(err, null); }
    });
 });
```

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the following line:

```
store: new MongoStore({
  db: dbOptions.db,
  host: dbOptions.host,
  port: dbOptions.port,
  username: dbOptions.username,
  password: dbOptions.password
},
function(err){
  console.log(err || 'connect-mongodb setup ok');
})
```

Simply remove the last function and I believe it should work as you initially expected

Contrary to Andrei's answer there, the MongoStore constructor does accept a callback. However it's not for error handling purposes - it actually passes back the collection property of MongoStore (which is why console.log spewed out what it did). If there's an error, MongoStore will simply throw an error. You can find it in the source code [by clicking here](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/blob/master/lib/connect-mongo.js#L41). The callback is invoked on line 164.

Comment: MongoStore does have a callback. The constructor has an arity of 2 and the second argument is indeed a callback. However, contrary to node standards, the first argument in the callback is not an error, rather, the collection property of MongoStore.

Comment: you are correct, that's the callback for a store, not session.

Comment: You missed the line for the callback... follow the code one step further. The call is on line 164 https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/blob/master/lib/connect-mongo.js#L164

Comment: It would probably also be useful to mention that the callback is there to signify when the driver has made a connection to the DB and is ready for commands. It allows you to alter the collection data without working through the `req.session` API.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, but I still can't figure out why the MongoStore doesn't work (I edited my question with more info)

Comment: Well that's the problem MongoStore doesn't trigger any errors so I guess the connection is established but no sessions is stored in MongoDB

Comment: Well I finally found out why I thought the sessions were not stored... I'm using [Mongo Express](http://andzdroid.github.io/mongo-express/) to visualize the database and the new sessions table wasn't showing up until I restarted the node server of Mongo Express. Also the logged-in session was kept from page to page but was lost when closing the browser because the session ID is changed, so I guess there is something more to do if I want the session to be kept even if the browser is closed

Comment: Glad you figured it out (-: